# angular 4 retrieve data from firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I try to retrieve data from firebase, but I got undefined value

the service code is

```
  getUserData():any{

  var that = this;

 firebase.database().ref('/users/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log("service UserData = "+ JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()) );
    return  snapshot.val();
        })  }
```

the home code is this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { UserDataProvider } from '../../providers/user-data/user-data';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    UserData1:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private userDateService: UserDataProvider) {

      this.UserData1 =   this.userDateService.getUserData();
      console.log("home UserData = "+ JSON.stringify(this.UserData1) ); 
  }
}
```

the code below return value from firebase and the result show in console

```
console.log("service UserData = "+ JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()) );

{"city":"iii","email":"iii@iii.com","first_name":"iii","isWorking":"","last_name":"iii","phone":"i","skills":"iiii","state":"ii"}
```

the code below return undefined  value from firebase and the result show in console

```
console.log("home UserData = "+ JSON.stringify(this.UserData1) );
```

home UserData = undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning data in getUserData function. try the code below

```
 getUserData():any{

var that = this;

   return firebase.database().ref('/users/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log("service UserData = "+ JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()) );
        return  snapshot.val();
})  }
```